# Calling WebApi for Windows Phone 8 Server not found

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, asp.net-web-api

I followed this tutorial: 
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-clients/calling-web-api-from-a-windows-phone-8-application

but I am lost when there is an ApiUrl, i had a problem on that because I can't seem to connect my windows phone 8 to my server. I use localhost in the phone setting but it does not seem to work.

What do you think I should do? This are my project files for the tutorial 
http://www.mediafire.com/download/ncnsedw8njcc7ua/TestWebApi.rar

The exact error is: The remote server returned an Error : Not Found

but when I tried accessing `http://localhost:55349/api/Books` I can see all the data on my

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read every step of the tutorial you are following especially this part:

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=324014

Comment: I did everything in their, still struggling that I can't work it out.
Still no server found

Comment: No I'm Good :) Just the option in the end where you will run IIS Express is quite misleading. I tried doing it in command prompt and it works flawlessly. I dont even need to do the proxy.